# Где в предложении поставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Еще полчаса тому назад левую сторону загромождали дома. Сейчас на их месте возвышаются дворцы. На крышах зеленеют сады на клумбах алеют цветы. У входа в каждый дворец стоят великаны.

Comment: Запятые, помогите пж.

Comment: На крышах зеленеют сады, на клумбах алеют цветы.

Comment: @НастяКот  **Запятые, помогите пж.** Странное у Вас обращение к людям — "запятые"! А **помогите пж** — вообще — ни к людям, ни к русскому языку отношения НЕ ИМЕЕТ.

Answer (score 0):

**Еще полчаса тому назад левую сторону загромождали дома. Сейчас на их месте возвышаются дворцы. На крышах зеленеют сады, на клумбах алеют цветы. У входа в каждый дворец стоят великаны.**

Если это связный рассказ, то я бы убрал все точки, кроме последней.

**Еще полчаса тому назад левую сторону загромождали дома — сейчас на их месте возвышаются дворцы: на крышах зеленеют сады, на клумбах алеют цветы, у входа в каждый дворец стоят великаны.**

Answer (score 0):

**Это переделка, а вот настоящий текст:**

Ещё полчаса тому назад левую сторону переулка загромождали серые многоэтажные дома. Сейчас на их месте возвышаются мраморные дворцы. БОГАТАЯ КОЛОННАДА УКРАШАЕТ ИХ ФАСАДЫ. На плоских крышах зеленеют роскошные сады на клумбах алеют, желтеют и синеют невиданные цветы. У входа в каждый дворец стоят великаны с громадными кривыми мечами в руках.

**Сокращение:**

Ещё полчаса тому назад левую сторону переулка загромождали серые многоэтажные дома, а сейчас на их месте возвышаются  дворцы.  На  крышах зеленеют  сады,  на клумбах распустились цветы.  У входа в каждый дворец стоят великаны.